# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require. [karma, webpack]

Tags: testing, webpack, vue.js, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am trying to setup karma for E2E testing of my Vue js app , but when I try to run npm test I get this error

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
at index.js:1
```

I am following official vue documentation on testing
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/testing.html

karma.config.js

```
var webpackConfig = require('../webpack.test.config.js')

// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // this is the entry file for all our tests.
    files: ['./index.js'],
    // we will pass the entry file to webpack for bundling.
    preprocessors: {
      './test/index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    // use the webpack config
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    // avoid walls of useless text
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    singleRun: true
  })
}

//index.js referenced in above karma config
var testsContext = require.context('.', true, /\.spec$/)    
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)

//webpack.test.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

module.exports = {

  module: {

    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        },
        include: [
          projectRoot,
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you have [karma-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-webpack) installed?

Comment: @craig_h yes I do have karma-webpack installed

Comment: It looks like the webpack preprocessor isn't being applied for some reason. You can take a look at a simple karma config I use for one of my projects to see if that helps you identify the issue: https://github.com/craigh411/vue-star-rating/blob/master/karma.conf.js

Comment: thanks @craig_h, changing preprocessor file path as './**/*.js', worked,
But the real issue was wrong index.js path given in preprocessor, It was suppose to be './index.js' and I had given 'test/index.js'.

thanks for your help , your comment made me look there

Comment: @Vishal If you have managed to resolve your issue, please put it in writing as an answer to your question! Otherwise yout might get downvoted and you lose points.

Comment: @oligofren thanks for reminiding, posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so the issue was a very silly mistake I made while giving path of index.js in preprocessor.

path should have been `./index.js` while I had given `test/index.js`.